# What use has the foil on hdds that are built in into notebooks?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I changed a lot of hdds in notebooks to built in ssds and always noticed the a foil on the hdds. I am wondering wath exact use it has?

Comment: Assuming it is part of the HDD assembly, it is for shielding.

Comment: Shielding from what, which direction?

Comment: +1, it'll be to help prevent EMC (electromagnetic conductivity) which can get you into a whole world of pain. [Layman's terms] - Electronic components that oscillate can generate a magnetic field, so the shielding prevents that magnetic field from interfering with the HDD. It could also prevent any electromagnetic field generated by a spinning physical drive from affecting other sensitive components on the motherboard.

Comment: It can only protect from the surface it was attached to. The other side has enough metal structure to protect it from that direction

Comment: Its an insulation for electromagnetic interference as far as I know, and somewhat works like a heat shield too